# UCCW/Tasker: Display system timer

Tags: tasker

I have an Samsung Galaxy S9 plus Default ROM but rooted.

I use my timer a lot with a default of 2.5 hours (medice req).
I have a nice UCCW theme customized to my specs.
I would love to have my timer displayed in there just like the clock. Is this possible in any form of way so I can display this with my UCCW skin ? (rebuilding the skin in KWGT is a option but not preferred.)

Comment: I got it partially working via KWGT UCCW cannot do this.
(source: https://www.reddit.com/r/kustom/comments/94wct4/countertimer_with_on_off_switch_possible/) `start with creating 2 text globals:
Name one endtime and leave it empty.
Name the second one cntdown with the value being tf(gv(endtime), "mm:ss"). 

Now all we need to do is add a touch action to anything, set it to toggle global switch > endtime, and set the value to $dp(a30m)$.`

Comment: whats left to go to timer settings on touch if timer is already running (otherwise it keeps reseting)